# Rails - Complex queries with ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have many complex queries to execute like the one bellow.
Is it possible (and worth the effort) to rewrite them using Rails ActiveRecord?

```
select a.name as athlete_name, a.nickname, t.name as team_name, top_scorers.goals
from (
  select g.athlete_id, g.team_id, count(*) as goals
  from goal g
  join tournament_edition te on te.tournament_edition_id = g.tournament_edition_id and te.tournament_edition_id = #{tournament_edition_id}
  group by g.athlete_id, g.team_id
  order by count(*) desc
  ) as top_scorers
left join athlete a on a.athlete_id = top_scorers.athlete_id
left join team t on t.team_id = top_scorers.team_id;
```

How can I rewrite it using ActiveRecord?

Model structure (legacy database):

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'athlete'
  self.primary_key = 'athlete_id'

  has_many :goals
  belongs_to :team
end

class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'goal'
  self.primary_key = 'goal_id'

  belongs_to :athlete
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :tournament_edition
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'team'
  self.primary_key = 'team_id'

  has_many :goals
  has_many :athletes
end

class TournamentEdition < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'tournament_edition'
  self.primary_key = 'tournament_edition_id'

  has_many :goals
end
```

**One Solution:**

After many tries I found this 'solution'. But I would like to get all information without use the map workaround, and a better way to use count as well...

```
goals = Goal.select(:athlete_id, :team_id, 'count(*) as goals')
            .joins(:tournament_edition)
            .where(tournament_edition: {tournament_edition_id: tournament_edition_id})
            .group(:athlete_id, :team_id)
            .order('goals desc')

goals.map { |goal| 
  {
    name: goal.athlete.name,
    nickname: goal.athlete.nickname,
    team: goal.team.name,
    goals: goal.goals
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please put your model structure here?

Comment: If it's doing what you want, i would not personally bother translating it into Rails.

Comment: I agree, also not worth translating into rails.  Sometimes the SQL is just easier to write and understand.